# How can I increase the maximum number of workspaces on Deepin 15.11?

Tags: workspaces, deepin, dconf, deepin-desktop-environment

I already tried both **com.deepin.wrap.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.num-workspaces** and **org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.num-workspaces** to 16 on dconf-editor and then rebooting my computer, but still I can create more than 4 workspaces. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this is an 'answer' to your question, but after digging around a bit I have found a few points that may be of interest.
The [Deepin Wiki](https://wiki.deepin.org/index.php?title=Deepin_Desktop_Environment&language=en#Add_Workspace) states that the max workspaces supported is 7.

I had the same issue with only being able to use max 4 workspaces, no matter what I configured using dconf-editor, until I read [this post](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/developer-center/issues/1121) that suggested `kwin` may be the issue, and by defaulting back to `deepin-wm` you should see an improvement.

So, I `sudo apt purge dde-kwin`, rebooted, and defaulted to `deepin-wm`. If you are not sure whether `deepin-wm` is still there, execute

```
sudo apt install deepin-wm
```

I reset the configs in your post to default, as by stating more than 7 workspaces, the system seems to break and reboot is required, and am now able to use 7 workspaces and view with the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> key combo.

I have not tried to revert to the kwin so have no idea if it will initiate correctly or not, but for me, I have a 7-window workspace switcher so I'll be sticking with it until kwin becomes an option again hopefully in the near future.

My `deepin` version is 15.11 Desktop.